# How to get the requested url in NAPT range extender for NodeMCU ESP8266 with Arduino framework?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266, arduino-esp32, esp8266wifi

I have a NodeMCU ESP8266 WiFi development board.

I was using the RangeExtender-NAPT example sketch in Arduino IDE for ESP8266WiFi library.
[You can find the code here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/RangeExtender-NAPT/RangeExtender-NAPT.ino) too.

It works great. I was able to connect to the ESP AP and was able to use internet. I want to implement the features below on it, but could not figure out how to do that.

1. I want to access the URLs requested by the user connected to the ESP access point. In simple terms, I want to monitor my ESP NAT router.
2. I want to block some IP or domain names or URLs. How can I do that?
3. I want do all this with the Arduino framework. (meaning, I don't want to use ESP-IDF, MicroPython, or CircuitPython).

Thanks in advance.

It would be also ok if the solution works for ESP32, ESP32 S2, ESP32 S3 instead of ESP8266. I have those boards too.

Comment: If you share the code you've tried to write to do these things, someone may help you to debug it. Otherwise you're asking us to write code for you, as the project you shared doesn't do any of the things you're asking about, and Stack Overflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).